# trouble with kubectl connecting to cluster on local net

Tags: kubectl

I'm fairly new to using k8s and `kubctl`, it is working fine with my EKS based clusters but when I try to add a cluster that is on my local network it fails.

Running on MacOS 13.4 (Ventura)
Kubectl version:
Client: v1.27.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource

I can't seem to get kubectl to connect to it, instead I have to use the dashboard (http://10.22.68.60:30539/) (TLS is not enabled). When I try to use kubectl with the cluster I get this "resource not found error", e.g.

```
E0713 12:38:21.469724   29296 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server could not find the requested resource
E0713 12:38:21.677199   29296 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server could not find the requested resource
E0713 12:38:21.891392   29296 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server could not find the requested resource
E0713 12:38:22.112032   29296 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server could not find the requested resource
E0713 12:38:22.328271   29296 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server could not find the requested resource
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Here is the command used to add the cluster:
`kubectl config set-cluster local_test --server=http://10.22.68.60:30539 --insecure-skip-tls-verify`

I've tried it with and without the `:30539` (which is the port the dashboard runs on).

The server's k8s maybe an older version, but I'm not sure how to get the version info from the dashboard (I can't ssh to it yet)?

Thoughts on other possible reasons why this might be failing?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `kubectl version`, it does not show the server version. You just need to install minikube for that. After installing you can use the apply and other commands.

Download on https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/